# Why can't Team Explorer connect?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

After having issues with VS2017 Enterprise memory leaks, but none with Team Explorer functionality, I've uninstalled and installed community edition.

- `tf settings connections` shows I'm connected
- `tf vc checkin` works just fine.
- `where tf` shows it is running the 2017 `TF.exe`
- removed my account from both the tfs section, and the vs sign-in in visual studio and added back.
- going to the project in a browser at `____.visualstudio.com` shows my login works just fine there too.
- removed connection from team explorer manager and it no longer has any hosted repositories showing in the `Connect to a Project` dialog
- `devenv /resetuserdata` as an administrator did not fix it
- going in the visual studio baked-in web browser, it comes up as already logged in and shows the projects just fine.
- I'm not behind a proxy
- deleted project's `.suo` file
- removed stored Microsoft account credentials from Windows 10 credential manager
- tried opening vs stand-alone (not opening a project to open it) and connecting

[image: Connect to a project dialog]

What causes VS2017 to refuse to show VSTS projects?

Comment: Does there show some error messages when connecting to VSTS projects? And can you show the related screen shots here?

Comment: What's the VS2017 version do you use? And what's the result if you install the latest version?

Comment: now, the most important project, is getting latest, and source control explorer works; but the connect to a project dialog remains empty, saying No servers found as above.

Comment: Does the email address you entered in VS (xxx@mail.com) same as the email address you login VSTS account in web page? Besides, you can double check in the users page (`https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_users`) to check if the email address xxx@mail is added in your VSTS account.

Comment: yes, that's the same email, and the page you sited, shows it is on the account, this was working with the same account before I uninstalled and reinstalled.

Comment: Please try to troubleshooting with below ways: 1. execute `tfpt connections` in Developer Command Prompt of the VS you installed. 2. select Add an account to enter the email address and password again (https://ibb.co/dkrSLd).

Comment: `tfpt` is not found in my 2017 developer command prompt. adding the account over again, did not change anything. nor hitting refresh again after the re-add

Comment: What if you sign in VS with the same email first (https://imgur.com/a/DAG0FPS), and then connect to VSTS again as the post (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/60295/no-servers-found-message-is-shown-when-using-work.html) mentions?

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same behavior today with version 15.9.5.
I also tried other options like deleting the VS related folders in %LocalAppData%, etc. to no avail.

The solution is to remove your account from within Visual Studio by selecting 'Account Settings' from the drop-down after clicking your name in the upper-right. Now remove the VSTS account, restart Visual Studio, enter your VSTS credentials anew and voila.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I did not try to clean local App data folder though.